# Azure Monitor Alert based on Custom Metric

Tags: azure-monitoring

I've created a custom metric to monitor free disk C: space on my Azure VM.
[image]

But when i'n trying to create an alert rule (not classic), i can't find my custom metrics in the options list. i'm thinking that this is due to the fact that i'm using the new Rule alrts insted of the Classic Rules.

Has someone succeeded to create a new alert rule based on a custom metric?

Using a query can give me the output, **but i don't know from where this info are coming (VM extension ? Diagnostic Log?)**:

```
Perf
| where TimeGenerated >ago(1d) 
| where CounterName == "% Free Space" and ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and InstanceName == "C:" and CounterValue > 90
| sort by TimeGenerated desc
```

Comment: How about just click the "New alert rule" button in the screenshot in your post?

Comment: As i wrote, problem is that when i'm trying to create new alert rule (include the button option) i can't find my custom metrics in the options list.